# How can I transfer data to html page from Web API redirect?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

How can I have a dynamic URL in a new page generated by a Web API redirect??

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string id)
        {

            var URL = "myurl";
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("mypage.html");           

        }
```

> ```
> <a href="{{myurl}}></a> ?????????????????? </body> </html>
> ```

Comment: Not sure what is going on in here but I see the method returns an HttpResponseMessage which means you can return 302 message header (Redirect) along with a URL you want the client to redirect to. Also, if this is an Ajax request, it won't work easily. You will need to detect 302 in JavaScript and cause a redirect yourself.

Answer (score 1):

```
[HttpGet]
public RedirectResult Get()
{
    string URL ="MYPAGE.HTML";
    return RedirectPermanent(URL);
}
```

I don't get what exactly want to do but if you want to redirect to specific Url then it can be achieved using this above way, but if you want to get url from the html then you need to pass Url as request param like below.

```
 [HttpGet]
public RedirectResult Get(string downloadURL)
{
  string redUrl="http://www.y.com/l.htm?"+downloadURL:
    return RedirectPermanent(redUrl);
}
```

From above, response will be redirected to that destination html page with download link as query string and you can set download link in your html page by taking from query string.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to get the variable generated in this way during a redirect. Are you sure, that you need this redirect?

Comment: How can I achieve that? On get method, user is redirected to a page that has a download link on it, this link needs to be passed through the api. Is there a better way?

Comment: Do you really want to redirect the user!? Do you use MVC in your project? Then you should create a view.

Comment: It's not MVC. It's a rest service. A mobile device consumes this service and then he gets redirect to a page that has a download link on it. Best solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same ideas to do it ,so that I have tried  to deal with this issue , hopefully my code can help you as following some methods
PS: one control to handle different web api Model

```
public class ff1Controller :BaseController<travel>
    {
        public ff1Controller()
        {

        }
    }
    public class ff2Controller : BaseController<a1>    
    {
        public ff2Controller()    
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is another way to do it, hopefully my way can help you

```
 private gigadeEntities1 db = new gigadeEntities1();
 public IQueryable GetAll(string id)
        {
            switch(id)
            {
                case "travel":
                    return db.travel;
                case "announce":
                    return db.announce;
            }

            return null;
        }
```